# How to connect to the Database?

Tags: php, mysql, chat

I tried connecting the database in order to create chat by using:

https://youtu.be/k8DhWcdKanM

I would like to know what do I need to change in this code in order to connect it to db:

```
<?php

    include 'dbh.php';
    $uname= $_POST['username'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $pass=$_POST['password'];


    $sql="insert into signup(username,email,password)

    values ('$username','$email','$password')";

    $result=$conn->query($sql);

    header("Location:index.php");

?>
```

Thank you.

Comment: What code do you have in `dbh.php` file ?? Could you share it

Comment: Please sanitize your input before submitting it into your Database, as this WILL lead to some sql injection, http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: Please don't put plain passwords in your database.

Comment: Kindly check with my answer and share your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Here is Connection Code.

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your variables names inside "values( )".
I believe it should be:
values ('$uname','$email','$pass')";

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to connect the DB from Another File you have to follow these steps

**Step 1:** `db.php` (Will provide two connectivity methods)

```
$host="localhost";
$user="phpmyadmin1";
$password="123456";// This can be empty in some cases
$db="XXX"; // XXX - DB Name

// This is First type of connection with returning
$con_1 = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$db); // Here the $con will be acting as the connection variable 

 // This is Second type of connection with returing
$con_2 = new mysqli($host,$user, $password, $db);
 // Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
   die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 } 
return $con_2; // This will return the connection variable to necessary pages that are needed.
```

**Step 2:** `signup.php`

In this we have to include the db.php file and then proceed with the connections.

```
<?php 
include('db.php');
$uname= $_POST['username'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$pass=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['password']);
$sql="INSERT INTO `signup`(username,email,password) VALUES ('".$uname."','".$email."','".$pass."')";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql); // Here we have to add the connection variable
header("Location:index.php"); // Used for Header Relocation
?>
```

> In the insert statement some of the variables like `$uname`,`$pass` are wrong. Hence the Query will fail and the insert operation will not be done. So kindly double check the variables and then proceed with the coding.

Hope this might be helpful for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbName);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";

return $conn;
```